# Is it possible to fit an interaction model (multiple linear regression) with many categorical variables?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction

Basically the title. I was trying to fit an interaction model with a quantitative response variable and 6 predictors - 3 quantitative and 3 categorical. When I tried to do it in R:

```
lm(voc ~ avg_cig * gender * age * race * edu * pir,
  data = nhanes) %>%
  summary()
```

What I get is more than 100 rows indicating how the categorical and quantitative variables interact with each other, which was very messy:

[image]

My goal is to figure out which of the 6 variables are significant and should be included. Is there a way to do this less messily while also using an interaction model?

Comment: This is the nature of interactions. I'm not quite sure what you're after here. Meaning no disrespect, it sounds a bit like someone asking if there's a way to add 2+2 so as not to get 4.

Comment: are you asking a) how to get p values and b extract coefficients with low p values? if so then its a stack overflow question on R
eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588638/ .. start with summary()$coefficients ....